# GetElementById interferes with ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender and asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to call a button click using JavaScript which is working. The code I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fncsave() {
            document.getElementById('<%= savebtn.ClientID %>').click();
        }
</script>
```

I'm also using an UpdatePanel to avoid the flickering of the page and I'm also using ajaxToolkit to add some animation to the UpdatePanel.

```
<ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="AniPanel1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Panel1">
    <Animations>
       <OnUpdated>
          <FadeIn Duration="1.0" Fps="24"></FadeIn>
       </OnUpdated>
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

My issue here is that when I call the button click using the JavaScript the UpdatePanel doesn't work along with the FadeIn effect of the ajaxToolkit.

If I remove the JavaScript part it works fine.

What can I do here to make this work? Any help will be appreciated it.

Comment: Is the `savebtn` a Button or LinkButton control?

Comment: Its a Button? Should I make it a LinkButton?

Comment: try making it link button and set its href="javascript:void(0);"

Comment: @jorame show more code. Also, check browser console for error messages. Which browser you use?

Comment: I really recommend that you stop using microsoft ajax toolkit if possible and start use something like jquery because Microsoft throw away the ajax toolkit long time ago